# Calculate both square roots

Tags: c#, math

In maths taking the square root of a number should give you both the negative and positive root. For example:

```
√4 = -2 and +2
```

However C# (along with most programming languages) will only return `2`.

So I could have a class like:

```
class PlusMinus
{
    double A;
    double B;

    public PlusMinus(double _A, double _B)
    {
        A=_A;
        B=_B;
    }

    public static PlusMinus Sqrt(double Number)
    {
        double A = Math.Sqrt(Number);
        return new PlusMinus(A, -A);
    }
}
```

But that does not then deal with equivalents to this such as `4^0.5` which also gives `-2` and `+2`, or `16^0.25` which gives `-2` and `2` again.

It seems then I should rewrite the `Pow` function:

```
public static PlusMinus Pow(double Number, double Power)
{
    double A = Math.Pow(Number, Power);
    if(Math.Pow(-A, 1/Power) == Number){
        return new PlusMinus(A, -A);
    }
    return new PlusMinus(A, A);
}
```

Which does work. However this does not seem the most efficient way to calculate *all* real square roots in C#. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't really think you should work with doubles for exponents here. Because all of the +/- results are for even integers or their inverse.

Comment: _However this does not seem the most efficient way_ Why do you think like that? Do you have a special reason?

Comment: @SonerGönül For each power I'm checking for the inverse power (`Math.Pow(-A, 1/Power)`). I think I'm effectively doubling the work the computer needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

when you raise a number to a certain power, there are two options.. if the denominator is even, and then you should put plus and minus, or the denominator is odd, and in that case, there only one root. so if you want to take all the real roots (sometimes there are more complex roots), you need to do the condition, and there is no more efficient way..